# Measurement of Cherubim in the Mishkan

Tags: shiurim-measurements, ark-aron-kodesh

Our son would like to bring in a model to school of the Aron, and cherubim (ark of covenant, and cherubim) that was in the mishkan. I found a box with the exact size of the ark. We would like to make model cherubim. Does anyone by any chance know what the measurements of the cherubim were in the mishkan? Thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed to make model cherubim?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Sukkah 5b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.5b.8-9?lang=bi), the Cherubim were 10 handbreadths (טפחים) in height from the tip of the wings to the base and their faces were *at least* one handbreadth in length (see [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.5b.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). I'm not sure any other measurements exist. We do, however, have additional measurements for the wings of the extra Cherubim Shlomo made for the First Temple:

> "In the Shrine he made two cherubim of olive wood, each 10 cubits high. [One] had a wing measuring 5 cubits and another wing measuring 5 cubits, so that the spread from wingtip to wingtip was 10 cubits; and the wingspread of the other cherub was also 10 cubits. The two cherubim had the same measurements and proportions." ([Melachim 1:6:23-25](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Kings.6.23-25?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en))

These Cherubim were larger than the ones of the Ark, but perhaps these measurements may be used relative to the size of the ones of the Ark ([according](https://www.temple.org.il/single-post/2017/07/18/-d7-9b-d7-a8-d7-95-d7-91-d7-99-d7-9d) to the Temple Institute, the two pairs of Cherubim were virtually the same except for the size).